# Обратная польская запись, нужен совет

Tags: c

Хочу реализовать калькулятор с ОПЗ.  Я создал стек,  туда я буду помещать операции(т.е. плюс минус умножить и тд),  еще я сделал очередь типа int на базе одномерного массива,  но туда мне нужно класть и числа и символы,  а массив типа int.  Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне поступить?  Как решить эту задачу?  Может нужно еще одну очепедь реализовать типа char  и туда символы писать?

Comment: Для начала предоставить код.

Comment: https://m.habr.com/ru/post/282379/  хочу как тут реализовать

Comment: А стек вы как организовали ? Массив выхода организуется точно так же, толь растет в другую сторону. Я бы и там и там клал бы структуры вида "тип, значение", где тип обозначал бы "оператор" или "значение", а в значении собственно значение или код оператора (которым в принципе может быть и сам "символ", он же для компьютера то же число)

Comment: Почитайте - Головиц Я. С++17 STL. Стандартная библиотека шаблонов (2018)
Подробное описание всего есть на странице 73

Answer (score 0):

А зачем в стек помещать операторы? В стек помещаются операнды. А при нахождении оператора из стека извлекаются нужно число операндов, производится действие и результат помещается обратно в стек

Comment: А если выражени длинное?

Comment: @Leeeo И что? Вы его разбираете и параллельно вычисляете